# Javascript function to retrieve information for all users

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have this function which helps me retrieve my friends ids, but i can't seem to make it work for retrieving one friend's id. I need to make a loop to get all friend ids.

Can you help me with this code?

```
function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    var testdiv = document.getElementById("test");
    testdiv.innerHTML = (
        response[0].uid2
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate over `response` :

```
for (i=0; i<=response.length; i++) {
   var uid2 = response[i].uid2;
   // do what you need to with uid2
}
```

[Docs for `for` here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

And to demonstrate how you would use it

```
function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    var testdiv = document.getElementById("test");
    var newhtml = "";
    for (i=0; i<=response.length; i++) {
       newhtml += response[i].uid2;
    }
    testdiv.innerHTML = newhtml;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks..
Would it be something like this?

for (i=0; i<=response.length; i++) {
   var uid2 = response[i].uid2;
   testdiv.innerHTML = (
        response[0].uid2
    );

}

Comment: Hey Manse, it's no excuse but i'm new to javascript, like really really new.. if i paste it exactly like this it won't work..

Comment: I did this and i have no output.. is it because i'm doing smth wrong here?...

unction(response) {
    console.log(response);
    var testdiv = document.getElementById("test");
    var newhtml = document.getElementById("test1");
    for (i=0; i<=response.length; i++) {
       newhtml += response[i].uid2;
    }
    testdiv.innerHTML = newhtml;
}

Comment: Solved :)
Thanks very much!
Sorry, you must be fed up with newbies like me, :)